# Find the values of m and n(Trigononetry in series)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

$$\sin ^6(1)+\sin ^6(2)+... ...+\sin ^6(89)=\frac{m}{n}$$

Find $\frac{m}{n}$ in its simplest form , and hence find both values. (All angles are in degree)

I've no idea how to start to solve this questions. Need some guidance for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are all the arguments to the $\sin$ in degrees?

Comment: Yes. The question states that all angles are in degree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align} 1 &= (\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t)^3 \\
&= \sin^6 t + 3\sin^4t \cos^2 t + 3 \sin^2t+ \cos^4t + \cos^6 t \\
&= \sin^6 t + \cos^6 t +  3\sin^2t \cos^2 t \\
&=\sin^6 t + \cos^6 t +  \frac34\sin^2 (2t) \\
\end{align} $$

let $$ S= \sin^6 1^\circ + \sin^6 2\circ + \cdots + \sin^6 89^\circ. $$ then we have $$\begin{align}2S &= (\sin^6 1^\circ + \sin^6 89^\circ) + (\sin^6 2^\circ + \sin^6 87^\circ) + \cdots + (\sin^6 89^\circ + \sin^6 1^\circ)\\
&= (\sin^6 1^\circ + \cos^6 1^\circ) + (\sin^6 2^\circ + \cos^6 2^\circ) + \cdots + (\sin^6 89^\circ + \cos^6 89^\circ)\\
&= 89 - \frac34\left(\sin^2 2^\circ + \sin^2 4^\circ + \cdots+\sin^2178^\circ \right)\\
&=89 - \frac 34 - \frac32\left(\sin^2 2^\circ + \sin^2 4^\circ + \cdots+\sin^2 88^\circ \right)\\
&=89 - \frac 34 - \frac34\left((\sin^2 2^\circ + \sin^288^\circ) + (\sin^2 4^\circ + \sin^2 86) + \cdots+(\sin^2 88^\circ + \sin^2 2^\circ \right)\\
&=89 - \frac 34 - \frac34 44\\
\end{align}$$

so $$ S = \frac{221} 8$$

there is an easier way to this. thanks to claude. see the comments below. we can express $\sin^6 x $ as a $\cos$ series in the following way:

$$\sin^6 x = -\frac{15}{32}\cos 2x +\frac 3 {16} \cos 4x - \frac 1 {32} +\cos 6x + \frac 5{16} $$ the $\cos 2x,\cos 6x$ sum to zero and $\cos 4x$ terms sum to $-1$   therefore the
$$ S = -\frac{3}{16} + 89 \times \frac 5{16} = \frac{221}{8} .$$

Comment: I think it should be $S = \frac{221} 8$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thank you.

Comment: I wonder if it could not be interesting to use the power-reduction formula of $\sin^n(x)$ for even $n$. For $n=6$, it would be $$\sin^6(x)=-\frac{15}{32} \cos (2 x)+\frac{3}{16} \cos (4 x)-\frac{1}{32} \cos (6
   x)+\frac{5}{16}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, do you any see massive cancellations?

Comment: The sums of $\cos(2x)$ and the sum of $\cos(6x)$ are $0$ and the sum of $\cos(4x)$ is $-1$. So $-\frac{3}{16}+89\frac{5}{16}=\frac{221}{8}$. I let you the problem of showing these three sums since you did most of the work. Cheers :-)

Comment: i see that now. it is much nicer way doing than what i did. you should write it up. the comments don't last too long.

Comment: Please, do it in your answer. I got the idea looking at your answer. So, you are the father of the idea. Very small gift to you with my pleasure. Do it !

Answer (score 3):

Found a way to solve from another site.

$$S=\frac{1}{8}\left(3\sum_{k=1}^{44}\left(\cos\left(4k\frac{\pi}{180}\right)\right)+221\right)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{44} \left( \cos \left(4k \frac{ \pi}{180} \right) \right)= \sum_{k=1}^{22} \left( \cos \left(4k \frac{ \pi}{180} \right) \right)- \sum_{k=1}^{22} \left( \cos \left(4k \frac{ \pi}{180} \right) \right)=0$$

Hence:

$$S=\frac{1}{8}\left(3\cdot0+221\right)=\frac{221}{8}$$